# jQuery: Calculating value from HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to calculate the Total value by choosing some shipping method then the value will  sum up with order subtotal.

but when I choose one of the shipping method then choose another one, the total value sum with the new and the previous chosen.
For example. at start total: 200 
then clicked "DHL standard delivery : $10.50" -> total = 210.50. 
After that, clicked "DHL express delivery : $42.50" -> total = 252.50, but it should be 242.50

How can I solve this?

Here's my jQuery code

```
 $("input:radio[name=shipping]").click(function(){
                var total = 0;
                $("input:radio[name=shipping]:checked").each(function() {
                    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
                });
                var current = parseFloat($('#total').val());
                $("#shipping").html(total);
                total += current;
                $("input:text[name=total1]").val(total);

            });
```

HTML code

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td>Select Shipping method</td>
<td>
    <input id="shipping_method" type="radio" name="shipping" value="10.50"> DHL standard delivery : $10.50<br>

    <input id="shipping_method" type="radio" name="shipping" value="42.50"> DHL express delivery : $42.50<br>
    <input id="shipping_method" type="radio" name="shipping" value="0.00"> pick up : $0.00<br><br>
</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Order Subtotal<td><label id="subtotal" value="">$200.00</label>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Shipping<td>$<span id="shipping">0.00</span>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</tr>
 <tr>               
 <td>Total<td>  $<input type="text" id="total" name="total1" value="252.50" style="border:0px;">
 </tr>
```

Comment: The code itself is flawed, You are adding Shipping+Total, which is wrong , you need to add Shipping+Subtotal, also you need to use a hidden input variable to store subtotal

Comment: Use subtotal remove $ or string parsing and use it as current.

Comment: thanks for your answer monotheist, it worked!.

Answer (score 0):

Try this notice i changed your total variables from appending.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 
                $("input:radio[name=shipping]").click(function(){
                    var total = 0;
                    $("input:radio[name=shipping]:checked").each(function() {
                        total = parseFloat($(this).val());
                    });
                    var current = parseFloat($('#total').val());
                    $("#shipping").html(total);
                   total =  total + parseInt($('#subtotal').text().replace('$',''));
                    $("input:text[name=total1]").val(total);

                });
            }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you want to add delivery to subtotal and not to total? My dictionary defines total as 'complete sum of a number of parts' meaning you shouldn't add anything more to it.
you need

```
var current = parseFloat($('#subtotal').text());
```

and remove the $ sign from its html